# Select an elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Select from specified elements to the parent element.
How to select exactly from the button as `class="bt-add-com"` To the above parent element `class="new-com-bt"` with jquery selectors?

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="post_id">
    <div class="new-com-bt" >
        <span>Write a comment ...</span>
    </div>
    <div class="new-com-cnt" >
        <textarea class="the-new-com"></textarea>
        <button class="bt-add-com">Post comment</button>
        <button class="bt-cancel-com">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)** and **[`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)** for that

```js
$('.the-new-com')
  .parent() // get parent
  .prev('.new-com-bt') // get previous element only if having the class
  .css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" class="post_id">
  <div class="new-com-bt">
    <span>Write a comment ...</span>
  </div>
  <div class="new-com-cnt">
    <textarea class="the-new-com"></textarea>
    <button class="bt-add-com">Post comment</button>
    <button class="bt-cancel-com">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Dear brother, actually i am making a post comment system, i have a form that is withing loop, then it created many form with the same class. So how i can handle and adjust the form, you answered me very well, but when i apply this one, it return lots of value from the class .new-com-bt why?

Comment: @ShaikhMujiburRahman :  I think you are using inside a click handler or an iterator... in that case use `$(this)` instead of `$('.the-new-com')`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the element with class "new-com-bt" is not a parent for the button with class "bt-add-com". More like an uncle.

Also, what did you try so far?

Anyway, try:

```
$(".bt-add-com").click(function(){
   var elem = $(this).closest(".new-com-bt");
});
```